# Redireccionamientos errores 400, 401, 403, 404, 500 htacces

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

Tengo el siguiente htaccess:

```
# Inicio No Cache

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|mp3|mp4)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2010 20:00:00 GMT"
Header unset Last-Modified
</FilesMatch>
#2 hours
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|xml|txt|xsl|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2010 20:00:00 GMT"
Header unset Last-Modified
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
Header set Cache-Control "public"
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2010 20:00:00 GMT"
Header unset Last-Modified
</FilesMatch>

# Fin No Cache

# Inicio No Navegar Entre Carpetas

Options All -Indexes

# Fin No Navegar Entre Carpetas

# Inicio Url Amigable

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?action=$1

# Fin Url Amigable

# Inicio Redireccionar

ErrorDocument 400 http://localhost:8080/checkLogin/
ErrorDocument 401 http://localhost:8080/checkLogin/
ErrorDocument 403 http://localhost:8080/checkLogin/
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost:8080/checkLogin/
ErrorDocument 500 http://localhost:8080/checkLogin/

# Fin Redireccionar
```

El error 404 redirecciona Ok, los demas no, por ejemplo:
El 403 cuando pongo la siguiente URL: http://localhost:8080/checkLogin/!!!_:-,-: me lleva directamente al error por default dandome acceso al localhost.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otro lado tambien tengo para filtrar las url pero pasa igual:

```
class EnlacesPaginas{
    public function enlacesPaginasModel($enlacesModel){
        if ($enlacesModel == "nuevoDepartamento" 
            || $enlacesModel == "nuevoCuenta"
            || $enlacesModel == "nuevoSite"
            || $enlacesModel == "inicio") 
        {
            $module = "views/modules/crudAbmUsuariosTablas/".$enlacesModel.".php";
        }
        else if($enlacesModel == "index"){
            $module = "views/modules/crudAbmUsuariosTablas/inicio.php";
        }
        else{
            $module = "views/modules/crudAbmUsuariosTablas/inicio.php";
        }
        return $module;
    }
}
```

Como puedo hacer para que cualquier error me redireccione a inicio? O que tengo configurado erroneamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías especificar en tu .htaccess las páginas de destino de esta manera:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.php
```

De esta manera le estás indicando la ruta a la página que debe mostrar el error.

Si quieres que todos los errores te redireccionen a la página principal de tu sitio bastará con poner en todos la misma dirección.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /inicio.php
ErrorDocument 403 /inicio.php
```

Comment: Claro, pero no seria esto que ya estoy haciendo en el htaccess?                                             
ErrorDocument 400 http://localhost:8080/checkLogin/
ErrorDocument 401 http://localhost:8080/checkLogin/
ErrorDocument 403 http://localhost:8080/checkLogin/
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost:8080/checkLogin/
ErrorDocument 500 http://localhost:8080/checkLogin/

Comment: Con `checkLogin` estás redireccionando a un directorio, no a una página de destino.

Comment: Mismo error, me redirecciona ok el 404, el 403 me deja en la pagina de error por default, le agregue el redireccionamiento al inicio